# Why does a specific site displays as "Error" in a react native Webview?

Tags: ios, react-native, webview

I am trying to display a french website called seloger.com into a Webview in my react-native application.

Since a few days, on iOS only, instead of displaying the website, the Webview displays an "Error" message.

[Screenshot: This is how it renders on Android, both Webviews are fine:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vrXR.jpg)

[Screenshot: This is how it renders on iOS (both simulator and real device), SeLoger.com Webview shows "Error:"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrXod.png)

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert, View, WebView, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class TestWebview extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop:20 }}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding:5, backgroundColor:'black' }}>
                <Text style={{ color:'white' }}>Google.com:</Text>
                <WebView style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    source={{ uri: 'https://www.google.com' }}
                    onError={() => Alert.alert("error")}
                    renderError={() => Alert.alert("error")}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding:5, backgroundColor:'black' }}>
                <Text style={{ color:'white' }}>SeLoger.com:</Text>
                <WebView style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    source={{ uri: 'https://www.seloger.com' }}
                    onError={() => Alert.alert("error")}
                    renderError={() => Alert.alert("error")}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Please note that onError and renderError are never fired.

This is the only website that I have found that causes such a behaviour. Which is bad luck, because this is the one I need to display in my app.

Anyone has an idea why iOS would not render this particular website and how I could circumvent this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround

Adding the following attribute to the webview causes it to display correctly.

```
useWebKit={true}
```

Comment: In IOS this will render to WKWebview. if it is not true, it will render to UIWebview which was deprecated by Apple.